# WPF DataGrid CanUserAddRows = True

Tags: wpf

I seem to have a problem with adding rows to a `DataGrid`through the interface itself.
Here is a screenshot of the UI:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, 0 rows were found in the database so nothing shows up in the `DataGrid` on the right side.
But id like there to be one empty row there, for manually adding rows. 
The `DataGrid.CanUserAddRows` is set to `True` but has no effect. 
Here is the `xaml` for the `DataGrid`, I have taken the liberty of removing some of the code to make it smaller.

**PrivilegeDetailsView.xaml**

```
<UserControl ...
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance impl:PrivilegeDetailsViewModel}">
    <DataGrid ...
              ItemsSource="{Binding RolesHasPrivilegesOnObjects}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" CanUserSort="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type int:IRoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectListItemViewModel}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" Binding="{Binding HasSelect, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanHaveSelect}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanHaveSelect}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            ...
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

**PrivilegeDetailsView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class PrivilegeDetailsView : IPrivilegeDetailsView
{
    public PrivilegeDetailsView() { InitializeComponent(); }

    public DataGrid PrivilegesOnObjectsDataGrid { get { return PrivilegeDataGrid; } }

    public IViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (IViewModel)DataContext; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }
}
```

Here is the `ViewModel (VM)` for the `xaml` `View` above:

**PrivilegeDetailsViewModel.cs**

```
public class PrivilegeDetailsViewModel : ViewModelBase, IPrivilegeDetailsViewModel
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private readonly IPrivilegeViewModel _privilegeViewModel;
    private readonly IRoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectViewModelAdapterRepository _roleHasPrivilegeOnObjectViewModelAdapterRepository;
    private ObservableCollection<IRoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectListItemViewModel> _rolesHasPrivilegesOnObjects;

    public PrivilegeDetailsViewModel(IPrivilegeDetailsView view,
                                     IRoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectViewModelAdapterRepository roleHasPrivilegeOnObjectViewModelAdapterRepository,
                                     IPrivilegeViewModel privilegeViewModel,
                                     IEventAggregator eventAggregator) : base(view)
    {
        _roleHasPrivilegeOnObjectViewModelAdapterRepository = roleHasPrivilegeOnObjectViewModelAdapterRepository;
        _privilegeViewModel = privilegeViewModel;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override sealed void Initialize()
    {
        _privilegeViewModel.PropertyChanged += PrivilegeViewModelOnPropertyChanged;
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ToggleSelectPrivilegeEvent>().Subscribe(ToggleSelectPrivilege);
        ...
    }

    public new IPrivilegeDetailsView View
    {
        get { return (IPrivilegeDetailsView)base.View; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IRoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectListItemViewModel> RolesHasPrivilegesOnObjects
    {
        get { return _rolesHasPrivilegesOnObjects; }
        set
        {
            _rolesHasPrivilegesOnObjects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        if(RolesHasPrivilegesOnObjects == null) return;
        _roleHasPrivilegeOnObjectViewModelAdapterRepository.SaveChanges(RolesHasPrivilegesOnObjects);
    }        

    private void ToggleExecutePrivilege(object obj)
    {
        var toggle = !View.PrivilegesOnObjectsDataGrid.SelectedItems.Cast<IRoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectListItemViewModel>()
                          .All(x => x.HasExecute);
        foreach(var selectedItem in View.PrivilegesOnObjectsDataGrid
                                        .SelectedItems
                                        .Cast<IRoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectListItemViewModel>()
                                        .Where(selectedItem => selectedItem.Object
                                                                           .CanHavePrivilege("EXECUTE"))) {
                                            selectedItem.HasExecute = toggle; 
                                        }
    }

    ...

    private void PrivilegeViewModelOnPropertyChanged(object s, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.PropertyName)
        {
            //When the SelectedSchema changes in the parent VM, I get the new rows to be shown in the DataGrid.
            case "SelectedSchema":
                RolesHasPrivilegesOnObjects = _roleHasPrivilegeOnObjectViewModelAdapterRepository
                                                  .GetPrivilegesOnObjectsAssociatedWith((IRoleEntityViewModel)_privilegeViewModel.SelectedRole,
                                                  (IContainerEntityViewModel)_privilegeViewModel.SelectedSchema);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `VM` for each row in the `DataGrid`

**RoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectEntityViewModel.cs**

```
public class RoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectEntityViewModel : EntityViewModelBase<RoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectEntityViewModel, 
                                                       RoleHasPrivilegesOnObject>, 
                                                       IRoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectListItemViewModel
{
    private readonly RoleHasPrivilegesOnObject _roleHasPrivilegesOnObject;

    public RoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectEntityViewModel(RoleHasPrivilegesOnObject roleHasPrivilegesOnObject)
    {
        _roleHasPrivilegesOnObject = roleHasPrivilegesOnObject;
        Role = new RoleEntityViewModel(_roleHasPrivilegesOnObject.Role);
        Object = new ObjectEntityViewModel(_roleHasPrivilegesOnObject.Object);
    }

    public override EntityType EntityType { get { return EntityType.NONE; } }

    public override RoleHasPrivilegesOnObject OriginalEntity { get { return _roleHasPrivilegesOnObject; } }

    public IRoleEntityViewModel Role { get; set; }

    public IObjectEntityViewModel Object { get; set; }

    public string ToolTip { get { return _roleHasPrivilegesOnObject.ToolTip; } }

    public bool HasExecute
    {
        get { return _roleHasPrivilegesOnObject.HasExecute; }
        set
        {
            _roleHasPrivilegesOnObject.HasExecute = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool CanHaveExecute { get { return _roleHasPrivilegesOnObject.CanHaveExecute; } }

    public override string Icon { get { return Object != null ? Object.Icon : string.Empty; } }

    public override string NAME
    {
        get { return _roleHasPrivilegesOnObject.NAME; }
        set
        {
            _roleHasPrivilegesOnObject.NAME = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I know this is a lot of code, I have stripped away a lot and put in place a few dots (...) to show that more code exist. NOTE: Im using [EF5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) and [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)

**How can I make the `DataGrid` accept new rows through the GUI?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I ended up doing was partially/Mostly what Maverik suggested.

I changed `ObservableCollection<IRoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectListItemViewModel>` to be `ObservableCollection<RoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectEntityViewModel>` and created a default constructor, which it didn't previously have.

The issue then was that the `RoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectEntityViewModel` needs some fields and properties set in order to function, so I created a public `Initialize` function to provided the necessary parameters.

I added an event handler to the `DataGrid's` `InitializingNewItem` event, where i called the `Initialize` function.

```
private void PrivilegesOnObjectsDataGridOnInitializingNewItem(object s, InitializingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var newItem = e.NewItem as RoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectEntityViewModel;
    if (newItem == null) return;
    var role = _privilegeViewModel.SelectedRole;
    var schema = _privilegeViewModel.SelectedSchema;        
    newItem.Initialize(role.OriginalEntity, schema.OriginalEntity);
}
```

When trying to adda new row, clicking the `ComboBox` didn't fire off the `InitializeNewItem` `event`. But clicking any other column fired off the `InitializeNewItem` `event`, and since at first each `Row's` `VM` had it's own `AvailableObjectTypes` property, the `ComboBox` `ItemSource` was not set if the `ComboBox` was selected before any other column, thus making it empty.

That was not an acceptable behaviour so moving `AvailableObjectTypes` to the `PrivilegeDetailsViewModel` and changing the `ComboBox's` `ItemSource` binding to this helped

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AvailableObjectTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Answer (score 15):

I believe your problem is using `ObservableCollection<IRoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectListItemViewModel>` as `ItemsSource`. In order for `DataGrid` to be able to create a new row, there has to be a type that can be constructed with an empty constructor.

If you changed it to say `ObservableCollection<RoleHasPrivilegeOnObjectEntityViewModel>` instead, i'm pretty sure your rows will start getting added.

Comment: And also the class needs a Default Constructor (empty)? Or maybe I can listen to an even or something for my own implementation for creating a new row, as my VM for each row kinda needs some parameters when constructed.

Comment: In that case, I guess you could use the `CellEditEnding` event and add a row manually