# DataGrid empty row by default (and always)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Good day!

I try to make DataGrid with empty row by default and if user delete all rows- datagrid shoud add e new empty row.

I try to do this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                              Name="dg1"     
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RowColl}"   
                                  CanUserAddRows="True"
                                  CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                                  IsEnabled="True"
                                  IsReadOnly="False"
> ...</DataGrid>
```

At *.xaml.cs:

```
RowColl = new ObservableCollection<Row>();
dg1.ItemsSource = RowColl;
```

But no empty row ..

Please, tell me how to get empty row by default and get always 1 row as empty.
Thank you!

Comment: Please look at [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330173/editable-datagrid-canuseraddrows-true-not-working), I think it has exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
myDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
```

It will display empty row at the end of datagrid view.

Comment: i can not find this field